# Clear input toggle to force page reload instead of conventional input clear

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to change the way the clear input option works.
By default, when selecting the X clear button, the search input is cleared.

Instead of clearing the search input when selected, I would like the clear input to trigger a page reload.

This is the X button in question:

[image: Clear input]

I have been able to create a click button in an input box which does this, but I would like to change to use the X which becomes visible in bootstrap once a user begins to typing.

Javascript:

```
$('#clear').click(function () {

    $('#input-outer input').val('');
     window.location.reload();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="input-outer">
    <input type="text">
    <div id="clear">X</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:"Tahoma";
}
#input-outer {
    height:2em;
    width:15em;
    border:1px #e7e7e7 solid;
    border-radius:20px;
}
#input-outer input {
    height:2em;
    width:80%;
    border:0px;
    outline:none;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
    border-radius:20px;
    color:#666;
}
#clear {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    top:5px;
    right:5px;
    border-radius:20px;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#clear:hover {
    background:#ccc;
}
```

What I am trying to change is instead of using this:

```
<div id="clear">X</div>
```

I am trying to target, bit with no success:

```
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
```

JSFiddle to hopefully help with my explanation: https://jsfiddle.net/mcmacca002/57mx3beq/1/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in the JSFiddle you are not using `jquery`..
After i have added it it seems to working..
(it does reloads the page)

Comment: Yes, but I would like to change ID clear to the bootstrap X which appears when you start inputting text. I just can't figure out how to capture that element